# How to cancel CHKDSK while it's running on windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, chkdsk

Whenever I have to manually shut off my computer, the next time it starts it runs CHKDSK. This takes forever and it never finds anything.

Anyways, it's running right now and it will be a while before I get to windows. It says "you may cancel this disk check, but it is strongly recommended that you continue" How? How do I cancel? I tried escape, control alt delete, enter.

When it says "you may cancel this disk check" is it lying?

Comment: have you tried CTRL+C or CTRL+Z ? - i never canceled it before, neither should you... im more a linux guy now anyway, cant test it.

Comment: **Do not cancel chkdsk**. Let it run and find out **why** it keeps running after you manually shut off your computer. There is a "dirty flag" on your harddrive and it should be reset or else you keep having this problem.

Comment: Describe _manually shut off my computer_. Are you pulling the plug, shutting off the power strip everything's plugged into, pushing the UPS off button, pushing and holding the computer power button till the machine shuts off, momentarily pushing the computer power button and letting the machine run its power shutdown routine or selecting shutdown from the start menu?

Answer (score 3):

Like i said above.
I would **not recommend** interupting chkdsk.

You may have a "dirty flag" set on your harddrive. Find out why.

You can try the following (after your computer starts up):

1. click on your start menu and open the run dialog.
2. type "cmd" and <kbd>return</kbd> (note: dont enter quotes)
3. Next type "fsutil dirty query c:"
4. If the return message indicates that the volume is dirty go to step 5
5. Next type "chkdsk c: /f /x" (this may require a restart)
6. After that finshes repeat step 3.
7. If it is no longer dirty then reboot and you should notice no more ckdisk.

Answer (score 1):

Highly unsafe even if you kill the chkdsk process (`taskkill /f /im chkdsk.exe`). *Chkdsk* locks the volume for exclusive access and termination of *chkdsk* may lead to unforeseen problems. 
If you shut the power down when one write is committed to the medium but not the other, the data can be left fully detached.

Do it on your own responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

It must be done withing the first 10 seconds of the check. 
Hold power button until computer goes off. Should give you a countdown when it restarts to bypass it.

During the first 10 Seconds of the check you should see the last line say something like "To skip disk checking, press any key withing 10 second(s)."

Press any key.